# Error while adding a Product In BigCommerce Store through API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I want to add products in our Bigcommerce Store through Bigcommerce API.

I have used following API to add a product in our store :-

URL : https://store-f8tya.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products

type : POST

data : row - json

```
{
    "name": "Plain T-Shirt",
   "type": "physical",
    "description": "This timeless fashion staple will never go out of style!",
    "price": "29.99",
    "categories": [21],
    "availability": "available",
    "weight": "0.5"
}
```

I am Receiving following Error :

> 415 - The specified input content type is not valid.

Note : I was asked to enter username and password. I have entered correct Username and token from Legacy API Settings.

Can someone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a content-type header? You need to specify if it is xml or json.

Comment: Thank you @Alyss. It worked.. :) (y) Can you please mention it in answer. So, i can accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to not specifying a content-type header. BigCommerce accepts XML or JSON as a type.